# UML meta-modeling

Tags: uml, profile

I have read about meta-modeling (including M0,M1,M2,M3)

I understood the goal of M0 (runtime execution), but I don't understand the meaning of M1,M2, can someone give a good example to where and how to define a profile? and what is the meaning of the tagged values in a profile?

Answer (score 0):

They are abstraction levels. The higher the number the more abstract the definition. The M3 level describes a framework in which you build your system. This framework is called profile. Imagine a car factory. They build cars. So in the profile you define such a car with what it would need. Then you can create a car class in a concrete model and it is distinct in certain respects (e.g. it must have 4 wheels, a motor etc.). Or take requirements: A requirement can simply be a piece of text. But in your modeling environment you might require them to have a distinction functional/non-functional, a source, a priority, whatever. So you define those as attributes in the meta-model and when you use the so defined Requirement stereotype the concrete class will have tagged values with the name of the attributes.